# How get data from the state and edit the element in the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to get the following effect: click button -> call function toggle -> save the index of the clicked item in the state this.state.index -> display edit form ---> get the data of the clicked element to the form -> edit data - > save

When trying to call the toggle function and write the `index` in a state, the index does not save. After saving the index in the state I would like to use it and have access to the clicked element in `todo = this.state.todos [this.props.index]`. I send the data of the clicked `todo` in the form attribute. In the form, he refers to this via `value = this.props.todo.date`. I'm using the `date-picker-react` library. Could someone guide me?

---

**App**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

   this.state = {

     todos: [],
     index: null,
     editing: false
   }; 
 }

 update = (propertyName) => (event) => {
   const { todo } = this.state;
   const newTodo = {
     ...todo,
     [propertyName]: event.target.value
   };
    this.setState({ todo: newTodo });
  }

  toggle = (index) => {
    this.setState({
    editing: !this.state.editing,
    index: index
  })
 }


 createTodo = (todo) => {
    const new = this.state.todos.slice();
    new.push(todo);
    this.setState({todos: new});
 }

 render () {
    return (
          <ul>
            {
              this.state.todos
                .map(index => {
                  <Todo
                   key= {index}
                   index = {this.state.index}
                   toggle = {this.toggle} 
                   todo={this.state.todos[index]} 
                   editing = {this.state.editing}
                   update = {this.update}
                 />
               })
            }
         </ul>      
   );
 }
}

 export default App;
```

---

**todo/Todo**

```
class Todo extends Component {
  render() {

    if (this.props.isEditing) {
      return (
          <EditForm
            todo = {this.props.todos[this.props.index]} 
            update = {this.props.update}
          />
      )
    }


    return (
      <li>
        <div>
          {this.props.todo.date}
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.props.todo.description}
        </div>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.toggle(index)}></button>  
      </li>
    )
  }
}

export default Todo;
```

---

**editForm/EditForm**

```
 class EditForm extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    }
  }

  todo(e) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const todo = {
      date: this.state.startDate,
      description: this.desc.value
    }

   this.props.addTodo(todo);
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={(e) => this.todo(e)}>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.update('date')} value= 
        {this.state.todo.date}
          showTimeSelect
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          value={todo.date}
          dateFormat="yy-MM-dd, hh:mm"
          timeCaption="time"
        /> 
        <textarea ref={(input) => this.description = input} value= 
        {todo.description} onChange={this.update('description')} 
        value={this.state.todo.description}></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>     
    )
  }
}

    export default EditForm;
```

Comment: todo/Todo: <button onClick={() => this.props.toggle(this.props.index)}></button>

Comment: Also in (App.update())() you're not updating this.state.todos[this.state.index], you're adding a new state property: this.state.todo, which I think is not right in your case

Comment: I guess, in update() function you wanted to do: const newTodos = [...this.state.todos]; newTodos[this.state.index] = newTodo; this.setState({ todos: newTodos, index: null, updating: false });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let each todo manage it's state, on edit it will show the form for that todo.

```
class Todo extends Component {

  state = {
    isEditing: false,
    startDate: new Date(),
    description: '',
  }

  setEditing = () => {
    this.setState({
      isEditing: !this.state.isEditing
    })
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  handleDescription = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      description: evt.target.value
    })
  }

  formatDate = () => {
    const d = this.state.startDate;

    return d.getFullYear().toString().substring(2) + "-" +
      ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
      ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + ", " +
      ("00" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
      ("00" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
  }

  onSave = () => {

    const { description } = this.state;

    this.props.update(this.props.index, { description, date: this.formatDate() });

    this.setState({
      isEditing: false
    })
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { todo } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      description: todo.description,
      startDate: new Date(todo.date)
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isEditing

          ? (<EditForm
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            description={this.state.description}
            startDate={this.state.startDate}
            handleDescription={this.handleDescription}
            onSave={this.onSave}
          />)
          : (
            <li>
              <div>
                {this.props.todo.date}
              </div>
              <div>
                {this.props.todo.description}
              </div>
              <button onClick={() => this.setEditing()}>Edit</button>
            </li>
          )

        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit form

```
class EditForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.props.startDate}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
          showTimeSelect
          timeFormat="HH:mm"
          value={this.props.startDate}
          dateFormat="yy-MM-dd, hh:mm"
          timeCaption="time"
        />
        <textarea onChange={(e) => this.props.handleDescription(e)} value={this.props.description}></textarea>
        <button onClick={this.props.onSave} type="submit">Save</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-todo-jp)