# Does DatePicker react have the "value" attribute as input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

Does DatePicker react have the "value" attribute as input?
Is it possible to assign the new value to the attribute **'value' ->** `value = {this.state.dates.date}` in the *DatePicker* component *(library date-picker)* as I did in input?

Expected effect: I choose date with datepicker -> later I choose a new date from the datapicker and overrides the previous date

---

```
this.state = {
    startDate: new Date()
}

 handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

<DatePicker 
  value = {this.state.startDate} //???????
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  showTimeSelect
  timeFormat="HH:mm"
  timeIntervals={15}
  dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd || HH:mm"
  timeCaption="time"
/>
```

---

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.dates.date} />
```

Comment: what do you mean by previous value?

Comment: @JuniusL. Correct. Changed 'previous' to 'new'.

Comment: that should be handled by `onChange`, when the value changes it'll update the value in the input.

Comment: please post your on change handler function.

Comment: @JuniusL.  update

Comment: you want to add new date to dates array?

Comment: @JuniusL. I want to take the old date and replace it with a new one, edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509312/how-get-data-from-the-state-and-edit-the-element-in-the-form/56510126#56510126), if you want to get the previous date, add a cancel button to your editForm/Todo component, when it is clicked it will cancel editing and won't save the new date.

```
onCancel = () => {
  this.setState({
    isEditing: false,
  });
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-todo-jp)

Answer (score 0):

It will not be possible in the way you did it, since you put the date in an array. So you have to tell which index of the array the value should be. However, if it can only be one date, then there is no use for the array. The scenario that you use a startdate and an array of dates is not clear to me, however...

If you want to keep the date in an array then it would be:

```
value = {this.state.dates[0].date}
```

or if you alway want to use the last date in the array

```
value = {this.state.dates[this.state.dates.length- 1].date}
```

however if possible I would consider to work with just one datefield in your state for the Datepicker

Comment: You have right.  I want to take the old date and replace it with a new one, edit it

Comment: yes I see your edit. Your initial value in the state is newDate. Have you declared newDate somewhere? Maybe you want to use ```new Date()``` instead?

Comment: I want to pick new date and replace old date

Comment: yes but you will need an initial value to begin with right? thevalue that is shown in the beginning. So the value newDate in your state should be defined somewhere. you can use ```this.state = {
    startDate: new Date()
} ``` to use current date as initial value.

Comment: I forgot paranthesis

Comment: There should also be a space between new and Date. Now it shows ```newDate()``` it should be ```new Date()```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194660/discussion-between-jelte-homminga-and-umbro).